# Adding multiple flat rates to Magento

Tags: php, magento

I've been searching online for a while and not having much luck finding the information I need to acheive what I need. Which is adding MORE flat rates to a Magento site.

I currently have all of the standard shipping methods in Magento. I have 5 flat rates e.g.

```
Flat rate 1
Flat rate 2
Flat rate 3
Flat rate 4
Flat rate 5
```

However I'd like be able to add another 5. The site i'm working on needs to have a fair few delivery options.

I've had a look online and can't find a detailed breakdown of what needs to be done. My PHP isn't great as a don't often use it, let alone working with Magento.

I'm assuming I'll need to extend the table in the DB and add the new flat rates, then add some logic to a controller somewhere. But really no idea where to start.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Magento ver. 1.4.1.1


*** UPDATE ***
```

It turns out the site is using this extension - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ig-multi-flat-shipping.html

I'm not sure whether it's customisable at the moment. However if anyone has experience extending past the 5 standard flat rates, please share any info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html

Just create a CSV sheet with "*" for all 10 entries and upload.